# About system time in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm starting work on a bash script that will shutdown my computer at a certain time of day, but I'm not really sure what all specifically needs to go into that. Could someone post an example of how they would do it?

Comment: I just looked back over my question, it probably isn't very clear. A better one would be, how would i get the computer to run a script every thirty minutes or so and shutdown when the time equal to when i want it to turn off?

Comment: There are a few ways to approach this depending on what you're trying to achieve. Open a terminal and type `man shutdown` to learn about how the shutdown command works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shut down at 22:15 every day, be root, run `crontab -e`, then add

```
15 22 * * * shutdown -h 5
```

on a line by itself.

Then save. At 22:15 every day, you will get a warning that the system will shut down in 5 minutes, and five minutes later, true to its word, it shuts down. If you want to abort the shutdown, run `shutdown -c` as root after the warning.

Comment: Thanks! Would give you some rep if i could.